# Is it possible for me to get an interactive PDF with high resolution images, yet a small file size? I'm talking under 5mb

Tags: pdf, resolution, file-size, compression

I am trying to create a digital portfolio of my work that I can email to employers. I want the images to be high resolution so my work is not viewed blurry and you can see some of the details in the projects.

However, I want to include some interactive elements such as app animations and website animations in the portfolio that will play as you get to those pages in the PDF.

I have created many versions successfully, however the file sizes are 60-80mb. Too large to email. I have gotten the file size under 5 mb but with very blurry images.

Can anyone advise me on how to achieve 49 pages of quality res images with some added interactivity with a file size at least 5-10mb.

Comment: I don't have to make a full answer here but if you're using a lot of svg elements it should keep the file size down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add "World peace" to your PDF... No... You can not have it all in life.

**Let's see your raw numbers.**

49 pages... 50 pages I am lazy with math. 5Mb That is 10 images per Mb or 100kb each.

Do your images look good using 100kb per image at the desired size? (Note I say size, and not the all mighty poorly understand term "resolution")

And by size, I mean specifically a MAXIMUM size of 1920x1080 px. and specifically using JPG compression... Then yes.

---

But if you say "High resolution" without understanding what high resolution is, just because one button say so, unless you have a vector format illustration, no. You cant.

You should not think of a jpg image to be zoomed to see infinite ammount of details. If that were the case, a PORTRAIT of a person at some point could look like this:

[image]

You need to stop at 100% image. That is your starting and ending point.

---

To achieve the smallest file size maximizing quality.

- Setup your images at 100% in pixels.
- Use vector images if you can.
- Leave text as text, do not vectorize it.
- Use RGB images, not CMYK.
- Reduce the image. Probably add a frame, put them in a different layout.
- Use the JPG compression you are comfortable with.
- Reduce the number of pages.

Comment: I'll work on the World Peace and let you know when I figure that out. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Upvoted for using my photo as an example. Even zoomed I recognised it!

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is uploading your PDF file to an online publisher platform like Kalameo, Issuu or Publitas*. With this you can upload your 80mb HR file, forget about optimizing, get a good image quality online PDF and send the link to your clients. They have a free version with limited, but enough features.

In my opinion the best one is Publitas:

- Extremely clean interface
- PDF viewer with no advertising except Publitas logo
- Allows you to include links or hotspots as is called on the application
- The possibility to replace the PDF keeping the same link, a good feature for updating your portfolio
- The feedback support with Publitas is immediate
- Responsive

Try the three platforms and keep the one that better fits you. Those are the links:

[Publitas.com](https://www.publitas.com/)

[Calameo.com](https://es.calameo.com/)

[Issuu.com](https://issuu.com/)

Here a top five of [publishing platforms](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/top-5-digital-publishing-platforms-angie-fisher/). I have no opinion because I don't know them.

---

<sub>*Checking Publitas's web, I'm not sure if they change the pricing plan because the free plan is not anymore there. Maybe they keep being free for old customers.</sub>

Comment: Seems like a good option, thanks for the advice.